# Doesn’t call user information to include “wp-load.php” in an external php file

Tags: admin, wpdb, wp-config, user-access, wp-load.php

Doesn't call user information to include "wp-load.php" in an external php file.

```
<?php require_once( dirname( dirname( __ FILE __ ) ) . '/wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb, $user_ID;

echo $user_ID; // reruns 0, always

is_user_logged_in() // returns false, always ?>
```

But I can check another one function will work. e.g. `get_bloginfo('name')` it will working.

**Note**: I can try to `require_once( dirname( dirname( __ FILE __ ) ) . '/wp-config.php' );` but results is same!

What could be the reason for this? Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Why are you bootstrapping WordPress manually in a dedicated file? There are far better and more reliable ways to build form handlers, AJAX handlers, etc, that avoid the security and performance implications of what you're trying to do. If you can tell us a little more about why you're using external PHP files by providing some context it would help greatly

Comment: In fact, I want to write a second admin panel, an additional one that contains some special MySql tables.. At the front end, Sync.

Comment: I was wondering what kind of a security breach it had.

Comment: How do you run this file? User information is in browser's cookie, so if you run this file from command line, you won't get anything.

Comment: You can build admin panels in themes, you don't need custom PHP files to do that, or to use custom sql tables. You could even build it as a javascript application and talk to authenticated REST API endpoints at `/wp-json`, and have no PHP files at all, not too different to how wordpress.com works. There is no need for stand alone PHP files that get called directly

Comment: in fact, depending on what these special mysql tables do, you could just extend the existing WP Admin interface, you can do SQL queries in WP via the `wpdb` API

Comment: @TomJNowell thanks. I will try to solve my work using wp api. it will be safer.